# Unity: allowing keycodes to shift with a variable

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, variables, keycode

I'm currently making a purposefully frustrated mini-game where the movement keys change each time you use them. I intended to do this with the code bellow.

```
public class Flop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string[] DirF = new string[] { "r","f","v","t","g","b","y","h","u"};
    private string keyF = "y";

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.keyF))
        {
            // insert code to do a little flop and select a new index to represent keyF
        }
    }
}
```

this is simplified from what I wrote, but essentially using the `keyF` variable to quickly replace the necessary input in the jump command. Initially I tried to make it a string as shown above, but clearly the `KeyCode` command doesn't accept strings and I have no idea what variable could be inserted instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Unity `KeyCode` enum seems like the perfect match for your use case. Instead of storing an array of strings, why not just store an array of `KeyCode`s? Your code would change to something like:

```cs
public class Flop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private KeyCode[] DirF = new KeyCode[] { KeyCode.R, KeyCode.F, KeyCode.V, KeyCode.T, KeyCode.G, KeyCode.B, KeyCode.Y, KeyCode.H, KeyCode.U};

    private KeyCode keyF = KeyCode.Y;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyF)) // We don't need to do KeyCode.keyF since keyF variable is already a KeyCode enumeration option
        {
            (insert code to do a little flop and select a new index to represent keyF)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GetKeyDown` method has both `KeyCode` and `string` forms for the argument. In your case, you simply need to pass the `string` representation of the key to the `GetKeyDown` method, as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html). As such:

```cs
public class Flop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string[] DirF = new string[] { "r","f","v","t","g","b","y","h","u"};
    private string keyF = "y";

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyF))
        {
            (insert code to do a little flop and select a new index to represent keyF)
        }
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to store an array of the `KeyCode` enums instead.

```cs
public class Flop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private KeyCode[] _dirF = new []
    {
        KeyCode.R, 
        KeyCode.F, 
        KeyCode.V, 
        KeyCode.T, 
        KeyCode.G, 
        KeyCode.B, 
        KeyCode.Y, 
        KeyCode.H, 
        KeyCode.U
    };
    private KeyCode _keyF = KeyCode.Y;

    void Update ( )
    {
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( _keyF ) )
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```